# Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in C:\wamp\www\zr\core\functions\users.php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm using PHP and MySQL. I am trying to insert form data from a web page to a MySQL database using a PHP function.

This is the code of the user form page:

```
<?php 
include 'core/int.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php';


if(!empty($_POST)){
$add_status = $insert->add_status($user_data['user_id'], $_POST);
}
?>


  <form action = "" method = "POST">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input name = "question_time" type = "hidden" value = "<?php echo time()?>" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Post your Question <?php echo $user_data['username'];?></h2>
                <textarea name = "question"></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit"></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </form>
```

and this is the function 'add_status' i am defining on another page..

```
function add_status($user_id, $_POST){

mysqli_query("INSERT into `post` (user_id, status_time, status_content) VALUES($user_id, '$_POST[question_time]', '$_POST[question]')");
}
```

When this runs on localhost it throws an error:

> Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in C:\wamp\www\zr\core\functions\users.php on line 97

I see that Line 97 is function `add_status()`

What does the error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do not use the depricated `myslq_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or pdo with prepared statements

Comment: You don't need to pass `$_POST` into your function - it's always in scope.

Comment: Get rid of the $_POST that is in the parameter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this

```
function add_status($user_id, $_POST){
```

You're declaring `$_POST` to be a local argument variable. By definition, `$_POST` is a superglobal (available to all scopes). So either you need to remove the argument and just let it propagate normally or you need to change it to a local variable like `$post` and use that instead.

```
function add_status($user_id, $post){
```

I would recommend the latter.

Some other notes: `mysql_query` and the associated arguments [are deprecated and will be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). Consider `mysqli` instead.

You're passing `$_POST` directly into SQL. That leaves you [wide open to SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). You need to fix that.

Comment: ya, I got this one thanks a lot.. But now there is a new error...you can see in the edited version...

Comment: @shivam You need to ask a new question then. Don't keep editing this question with new problems after that one has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `$_POST` as another local variable because that is defined in php as a global variable with read-only attribute. To solve the problem, just use another variable name instead of `$_POST` in the function definition `add_status`. Ex:

```
function add_status($user,$postVar){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$_POST is a global variable, and as is it says in the error you cannot reassign it.
You mus change you function declaration by

```
function add_status($user_id, $values){
  mysql_query("INSERT into `post` (user_id, status_time, status_content) VALUES($user_id, '$values[question_time]', '$values[question]')");
}
```

@jens says :

> Do not use the depricated myslq_* API. Use mysqli_* or pdo with prepared statements –  Jens

you should replace that to

Answer (score 1):

use following code

```
function add_status($user_id){
$qt = $_POST[question_time];
$q=$_POST[question];
mysqli_query("INSERT into `post` (user_id, status_time, status_content) VALUES($user_id, '$qt', '$q')");
}
```

It should work for you.

Comment: You still leave it wide open to SQL injection

Comment: @Machavity Its a good point but issue to resolve is code failing